# mongodb config error for storage engine mmapv1 with samllFiles

Tags: mongodb

I am receiving this error when trying to start mongodb

```
2015-12-25T08:45:24.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2132 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=sulubuntu
2015-12-25T08:45:24.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.8
2015-12-25T08:45:24.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 83d8cc25e00e42856924d84e220fbe4a839e605d
2015-12-25T08:45:24.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-187-89-126 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64$2015-12-25T08:45:24.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-12-25T08:45:24.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/$2015-12-25T08:45:24.441+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected configuration for non-active storage engine mmapv1 when current storage engine is
2015-12-25T08:45:24.442+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 18656 Cannot start server with an unknown storage engine: , terminating
2015-12-25T08:45:24.442+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

This is my config file

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: false
  engine:
  mmapv1:
    smallFiles: true
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

**the error goes away if I comment out these values: engine, mmapv1, smallFiles**

This looks like a config error but I am just following the guidelines on writing config files [found here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/)

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is that you cannot leave the `storage.engine` key empty IF you specify it. In other words it does default to `mmapv1` but only if you don't add it at all.

This is a working  configuration I have on a server of mine:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
    logAppend: true

storage:
    mmapv1:
        smallFiles: true
    engine: mmapv1
    journal:
        enabled: true
    dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb"

net:
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1
    port: 27017
```

For MongoDB 3.0 the engine key could be omitted as it defaults to `mmapv1`, but since from 3.2 onwards it defaults to `wiredTiger`, I would recommend making it explicit and avoid headaches when upgrading....

Comment: where to see this configuration file?

Comment: It is part of the mongod.conf file that contains the mongodb server configuration. It's precise location depends on how you installed mongodb and which os / Linux distro you are using.